# Getting different hash value with puppet exec

Tags: jboss, md5, puppet, jboss-eap-6, puppet-enterprise

When I have executed the following command I am getting the perfect hash value which i have expected.

```
/opt/Jboss/dc/bin/add-user.sh --silent --user testuser --password testuser*1 --realm ManagementRealm
```

**Hash Logic = md5(testuser:ManagementRealm:testuser*1)**

**Expected hash value = e72bfb358dd2116ad0033c01e357c1b2**

But when i have tried the same thing with puppet exec. I am getting different hash value. I don't know how to debug or fix it. Any help is much appreciated.

my puppet code :

```
define jboss::useradd(
$home,
$username,
$password,
) {
        $jbossuserfix   = '2>&1 | awk \'BEGIN{a=0}{if (/Error/){a=1};print}END{if (a==1) exit 1}\''
        $realm          = "ManagementRealm"
        $filepath       = "${home}/domain/configuration/mgmt-users.properties"
        $encrypasswd    = md5("${username}:ManagementRealm:${password}")
        notify { " ${title} Encry ${encrypasswd} ": }
        exec { "${title}::user::add":
                environment => ["JBOSS_HOME=${home}","__PASSWD=${password}"],
                command     => "${home}/bin/add-user.sh --silent --user '${username}' --password \"\$__PASSWD\" --realm '{realm}' ${jbossuserfix}",
                unless      => "/bin/egrep -e '^${username}=${encrypasswd}' ${filepath}",
                require     => File["${home}/domain/configuration/domain.xml"],
                logoutput   => true,
        }
}
```

The following is the result i am getting with my above code.

**Result hash value : fb8ed958ba3d535fb8314d4da4b96d42**

Comment: Can't reproduce: `puppet apply -e 'notice md5("testuser:ManagementRealm:testuser*1")'` gives me `e72bfb358dd2116ad0033c01e357c1b2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `command` attribute in your puppet code doesn't match the example line you give.

First, you're missing the `$` on `${realm}`.

Second, you've added quotes around the parameters in the puppet code. Not knowing anything about the script you are calling, that may or may not be important.